# Extracting subscription data from ChargeBee to google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, chargebee

How to use API to get subscription data (Customer name; value of subscription; payment status;) into a google spreadsheet from Chargebee?

I am aware of ChargeBee Subscription API documentation,
(https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api/subscriptions?prod_cat_ver=1#retrieve_a_subscription)

Still, not sure how to use them and fetch data into a google spreadsheet.

First time working on an API, very little clue on how to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in a real world scenario you have to fetch huge list of subscription data, instead of exporting data from Chargebee via API. The correct and easiest approach will be to export via Export/Import GUI available in Web Console. The export file will be in CSV/Excel Sheet format which you can upload to the Google Spreadsheet.

[image: Chargebee Web Console]

Answer (score 0):

we're building a tool specifically for this right now. [StackIt](https://nowstackit.com) is a spreadsheet automation tool that connects with multiple SaaS tools and brings data to sheets automatically. We're live with Chargebee integration. You can download it from Google's [marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/stackit_connector_for_postgresql_mysql/909601158724)